# Bad return type in lambda expression void converted to int

Tags: java, lambda

I've just started out using lambdas and wrote this code to calculate if an input year is a leapyear or not, using lambdas.

I get the error "bad return type in lambda expressions void cannot be converted to int" and to no avail searched for answers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

interface LeapYears {
    int leapYear(int years);
}

public class LeapYear {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        LeapYears leap = (t) -> {
            System.out.print("Year between 2012 and 2060: ");
            int years = in.nextInt();
            boolean x = years % 4 == 0,
                    y = years % 100 != 0,
                    z = years % 400 == 0;

            boolean isLeapYear = (x && y) || z;
            if (isLeapYear == true) {
                return System.out.println(years + " Is a Leapyear");
            } else {
                return System.out.println(years + " is not a Leapyear");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know System.our.println has no return type. Why do you think it will return you an int?

Comment: It seems like you're looking for a `Predicate` if you really want to use a lambda.

Comment: You declared your function as `int leapYear(int years); `, but you are returning `void`. On this one, it has no connection with the lambda. You should return a boolean instead, and deal with the printing in the main calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

you have some mistakes in your code

```
interface LeapYears {
    boolean leapYear(int years); // should return true or false
}

public class LeapYear {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Year between 2012 and 2060: ");
    int years = in.nextInt(); // get year from user
    // that lamda is like anonymouse class!
    LeapYears leap = (t) -> {
        boolean x = t % 4 == 0; // it looked bad
        boolean y = t % 100 != 0; 
        boolean z = t % 400 == 0;

        boolean isLeapYear = (x && y) || z;
        return isLeapYear; // have to return boolean
    };

    // check the leap there and print answer
    if (leap.leapYear(years) == true) {
        System.out.println(years + " Is a Leapyear");
    } else {
        System.out.println(years + " is not a Leapyear");
    }
  }
}
```

Answering to your question: System.out.println doesn't return any type.
Try to write more readable code and you need to read about SOLID principles

Answer (score 0):

You wrote
`return System.out.println(years + " Is a Leapyear");` but `System.out.println` returns void, so you're returning nothing.

[Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println())

> `public void println()` 
>  
>   Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The line separator string is defined by the system property `line.separator`, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n').

As you can see it returns void, why do you think it would return an integer?

---

You should return the `boolean isLeapYear` variable and check if it is true in these lines, which should be outside the lambda instead of inside.

```
if (leap.leapYear(years) == true) {
    return System.out.println(years + " Is a Leapyear");
} else {
    return System.out.println(years + " is not a Leapyear");
}
```